# Reducing the overlapping count number of buses running from a city to different stopage in straight line, and can my current approach be optimised?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, stack

Given pair of distance of start distance and end distance, reduces the number of buses if there is an overlapping in two stopage.
for e.g:

```
input n=4
{2,8},{6,10},{12,14},{12,20}
output:2
explanation:route {2,8} and {6,10} overlap so it can be reduced to 1 route as {2,10}
similarly route {12,14} and {12,20} overlap it can be merged to 1.

input n=4
{1,3} ,{7,9}, {4,6},{10,13}
output=4 since there is no overlapping
```

my approach: I have tried to sort `vector<pair<int,int>>` in descending order,and push into `stack<pair<int,int>>` and have used a counter `count` that counts the unique route and pops the stack checking the condition,till its gets empty. **Despite my code appears 100% correct to me but it does not output anything when there is no overlapping in route.**, for e.g for input `n=4`, route: `{1,3} ,{7,9}, {4,6},{10,13}` it does not output anything. looking for help to tackle such problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
bool compare(pair<int,int>p1,pair<int,int>p2){
    return p1.first>p2.first;
}
int main(){
    int n;cin>>n;
    vector<pair<int,int>>v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int u,w;
        cin>>u>>w;
        v.push_back(make_pair(u,w));
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);
    stack<pair<int,int>>st;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        st.push(v[i]);
    }
    //looking for help from here ,basically i dont understands why my code in stack fails
    int count=0;
    while (!st.empty()){
        pair<int,int>y=st.top();
        st.pop();
        count++;
        if(y.second>=st.top().first){
            if(st.size()>0){
                 st.pop();
            }
        }

    }
    cout<<count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is at `if(y.second >= st.top().first)`. What if `st` is empty here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
bool compare(pair<int,int>p1,pair<int,int>p2){
    return p1.first>p2.first;
}
int main(){
    int n;cin>>n;
    vector<pair<int,int>>v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int u,w;
        cin>>u>>w;
        v.push_back(make_pair(u,w));
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);
    stack<pair<int,int>>st;
    for(int i=0;i<int(v.size());i++){
        st.push(v[i]);
    }
    //looking for help from here ,basically i dont understands why my code in stack fails
    int count=0;
    while (!st.empty()){
        pair<int,int>y=st.top();
        st.pop();
        count++;
        if(st.size()>0){
            if(y.second>=st.top().first){
                st.pop();
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<'\n';
}
```

Just move `if(st.size() > 0)` outside and your code will run properly.

Comment: Thank you for answer, can it be optimised!

Comment: @def__init__ The complexity of the code is `O(nlogn)` because of sorting which should be fast enough, but you can still do some constant optimization such as adding `ios::sync_with_stdio(0);` and `cin.tie(0);` at the start of `main()`;

Comment: yeah, unneccessary copying to stack, can be optimised? like to find other way to do this and have better optimisation

Comment: @def__init__ There might be ways to optimize to `O(n)` but it is beyond my scope of knowledge. If that is what you want, I think you should post another question.  However, if you are trying to get your solution to pass some online judge, it's very likely that a lack of fastIO of c++ is the issue.

Comment: okay thank you so much for your kind answer!

Comment: @def__init__ yes, the stack can be optimised away, but it won't affect the performance a lot. I can try that for you if you want though.

Comment: @def__init__ if this or other answers has solved your questions, can you please consider accepting it to indicate to a wider audience that the problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling top on an empty stack.

You are checking that stack shouldn't be empty before going in while loop body. So consider the case where stack has just one element, while loop check passed, you went inside. Called pop once, your stack is now empty. Then you call top, which is essentially on an empty stack.